# ON my father's/mothers's side

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Let's say your father's side has a family history of diabetes. Do you still use the preposition "ON", and is this a correct construction:

Question: What motivates you to exercise daily?

> Answer: Well, because, "**ON** my father's side, **they've got a family history of diabetes.**

Is this the correct "fixed phrase" to say that in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *itself* is fine, but the construction of your sentence in which you included it is a little unusual.

I would restructure it in the following way:

> "Because there is a history of diabetes **on my father's side** of the family."

---

Alternatively, a different version can be used if the preposition *on* is removed:

> "Because **my father's side** of the family has a history of diabetes."